# Merge a csv and shapefile with geopandas

Tags: python, csv, geopandas, shapefile

I'm trying to merge a CSV with a shapefile using geopandas.  I have a unique ID for both and would like to attach data from the CSV into the shapefile when there is a matching unique ID.  Thanks

Comment: you should be able to just use pd.merge. Can you show us where you're stuck? see this guide on [how to ask a question](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- here is a complete working example
- load downloaded shape file of US states
- load CSV (use `io.StringIO` to make this code standalone)
- **pandas** `merge()` on key column *iso_3166_2*
- show it's worked by plotting merged data, geometry from shape file, *size* from CSV

```
import io
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib
import requests

# fmt: off
# download boundaries
url = "https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces.zip"
f = Path.cwd().joinpath(urllib.parse.urlparse(url).path.split("/")[-1])
# fmt: on

if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    zfile.extractall(f.stem)

# load downloaded boundaries (shape file)
gdf2 = gpd.read_file(str(f.parent.joinpath(f.stem).joinpath(f"{f.stem}.shp")))

# load CSV....
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""size,iso_3166_2
118,US-MN
829,US-MT
235,US-ND
998,US-ID
807,US-WA
956,US-AZ
2094,US-CA
652,US-CO
541,US-NV
1,US-WV
3,US-MD
2,US-NJ
8,US-NY
16,US-PA
1,US-ME
66,US-MI"""))

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df.merge(gdf2, on="iso_3166_2"))

# prove it worked...
gdf.plot(column="size", cmap="OrRd")
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer Rob Raymond, this is extremely helpful!